# Monitoring CPU fan speed on Lenovo system x3650 m5 (8871) on RHEL7

Tags: rhel, monitoring, fan

I need to monitor an Lenovo system x3650 m5 (8871) server. Unfortunately `lm_sensor` just show the CPU temperature. Do anyone have an advice,  how I could monitor the fan speed with an commandline tool?

Output sensors:

```
sensors
power_meter-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
power1:      141.00 W  (interval =   1.00 s)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +30.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 0:         +21.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 2:         +23.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 3:         +22.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 4:         +22.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 8:         +23.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 10:        +20.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 11:        +21.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 12:        +20.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 1:  +28.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 0:         +22.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 2:         +22.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 3:         +21.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 4:         +21.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 8:         +22.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 10:        +21.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 11:        +21.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
Core 12:        +22.0°C  (high = +92.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)
```

**Output sudo sensors-detect**

```
sensors-detect
# sensors-detect revision 3.4.0-4 (2016-06-01)
# System: LENOVO System x3650 M5: -[8871AC1]- [13]
# Board: LENOVO 01KN179
# Kernel: 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2667 v4 @ 3.20GHz (6/79/1)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): 
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): 
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x3711
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x7f00

Some systems (mainly servers) implement IPMI, a set of common interfaces
through which system health data may be retrieved, amongst other things.
We first try to get the information from SMBIOS. If we don't find it
there, we have to read from arbitrary I/O ports to probe for such
interfaces. This is normally safe. Do you want to scan for IPMI
interfaces? (YES/no): 
Found `IPMI BMC KCS' at 0xcc0...                            Success!
    (confidence 8, driver `to-be-written')

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): 
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): 
Found unknown SMBus adapter 8086:8d22 at 0000:00:1f.3.
Sorry, no supported PCI bus adapters found.
Module i2c-dev loaded successfully.

Next adapter: mga i2c (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 1fe0 (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 
Client found at address 0x48
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM75A'...               No
Probing for `Dallas Semiconductor DS75'...                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM77'...                No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7410/ADT7420'...             No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7411'...                     No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6642'...                              No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP435'...                   No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM73'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM92'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM76'...                No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6633/MAX6634/MAX6635'...              No
Probing for `NXP/Philips SA56004'...                        No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1023'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1043'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1053'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1063'...                               No


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `to-be-written':
  * ISA bus, address 0xcc0
    Chip `IPMI BMC KCS' (confidence: 8)

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

Note: there is no driver for IPMI BMC KCS yet.
Check http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/Devices for updates.

Do you want to overwrite /etc/sysconfig/lm_sensors? (YES/no): 
Unloading i2c-dev... OK
```

**Output find /sys/ -iname '*fan*'**

```
  # find /sys/ -iname '*fan*'
    /sys/bus/platform/drivers/acpi-fan
    /sys/kernel/slab/fanotify_event_info
    /sys/kernel/slab/fanotify_perm_event_info
    /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_fanotify_init
    /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_exit_fanotify_init
    /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_fanotify_mark
    /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_exit_fanotify_mark
    /sys/module/rcutree/parameters/rcu_fanout_leaf
```

*English is not my native, so please  don't judge my spelling errors. I am also not sure, if this is the correct site for this Question.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system has a correctly configured BMC with IPMI support, so you should be able to use `ipmitool` locally to extract all the monitoring information supported by your BMC:

```
yum install ipmitool
ipmitool sensor
```

(assuming the `ipmi_si` module is loaded, which should be the case on RHEL 7 on your setup). The interesting values are in the first two columns (sensor and value), and the fourth (health indicator):

```
CPU Temp         | 45.000     | degrees C  | ok    | 0.000     | 0.000     | 0.000     | 91.000    | 96.000    | 96.000    
System Temp      | 37.000     | degrees C  | ok    | -10.000   | -5.000    | 0.000     | 80.000    | 85.000    | 90.000    
Peripheral Temp  | 43.000     | degrees C  | ok    | -10.000   | -5.000    | 0.000     | 80.000    | 85.000    | 90.000    
MB_10G Temp      | 50.000     | degrees C  | ok    | -5.000    | 0.000     | 5.000     | 95.000    | 100.000   | 105.000   
DIMMA1 Temp      | 42.000     | degrees C  | ok    | -5.000    | 0.000     | 5.000     | 80.000    | 85.000    | 90.000    
DIMMA2 Temp      | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        
DIMMB1 Temp      | 42.000     | degrees C  | ok    | -5.000    | 0.000     | 5.000     | 80.000    | 85.000    | 90.000    
DIMMB2 Temp      | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        
FAN1             | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        
FAN2             | 3300.000   | RPM        | ok    | 300.000   | 500.000   | 700.000   | 25300.000 | 25400.000 | 25500.000 
FAN3             | 900.000    | RPM        | ok    | 300.000   | 500.000   | 700.000   | 25300.000 | 25400.000 | 25500.000 
FAN4             | na         |            | na    | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na        
VCCP             | 1.830      | Volts      | ok    | 1.420     | 1.460     | 1.570     | 2.020     | 2.130     | 2.170     
VDIMM            | 1.182      | Volts      | ok    | 0.948     | 0.975     | 1.047     | 1.344     | 1.425     | 1.443     
12V              | 12.000     | Volts      | ok    | 10.144    | 10.272    | 10.784    | 12.960    | 13.280    | 13.408    
5VCC             | 4.974      | Volts      | ok    | 4.246     | 4.298     | 4.480     | 5.390     | 5.546     | 5.598     
3.3VCC           | 3.333      | Volts      | ok    | 2.789     | 2.823     | 2.959     | 3.554     | 3.656     | 3.690     
VBAT             | 3.168      | Volts      | ok    | 2.385     | 2.472     | 2.588     | 3.487     | 3.574     | 3.690     
5V Dual          | 4.946      | Volts      | ok    | 4.244     | 4.298     | 4.487     | 5.378     | 5.540     | 5.594     
3.3V AUX         | 3.265      | Volts      | ok    | 2.789     | 2.823     | 2.959     | 3.554     | 3.656     | 3.690     
Chassis Intru    | 0x0        | discrete   | 0x0000| na        | na        | na        | na        | na        | na
```