# Monitoring Power Supply on Lenovo system x3650 m5 (8871) on RHEL7

Tags: rhel, monitoring, power-management

This question is related to  [Monitoring CPU fan speed on Lenovo system x3650 m5 (8871) on RHEL7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346774/monitoring-cpu-fan-speed-on-lenovo-system-x3650-m5-8871-on-rhel7/346849#346849). After the monitoring of the Fan i need to monitor the status of the Power Supply. Here `ipmitool` doesn't work, (it show false positive results). The Server has 2 power supplies. I need to know when one or both are down/inactive. How I could monitor the power supplies with a command-line tool?

I did use the `ipmitool sdr type Other` command. The Output was

```
PS Heavy Load    | 0Dh | ok  | 19.1 | State Deasserted
Power Supply 1   | E0h | ok  | 10.1 | Presence detected
Power Supply 2   | E1h | ok  | 10.2 | Presence detected
PS Configuration | E2h | ok  | 19.1 | 
PS 1 Therm Fault | E5h | ok  | 10.1 | Transition to OK
PS 2 Therm Fault | E6h | ok  | 10.2 | Transition to OK
PS1 12V OV Fault | E7h | ok  | 10.1 | Transition to OK
PS2 12V OV Fault | E8h | ok  | 10.2 | Transition to OK
PS1 12V UV Fault | E9h | ok  | 10.1 | Transition to OK
PS2 12V UV Fault | EAh | ok  | 10.2 | Transition to OK
PS1 12V OC Fault | EBh | ok  | 10.1 | Transition to OK
PS2 12V OC Fault | ECh | ok  | 10.2 | Transition to OK
PS1 12Vaux Fault | EDh | ok  | 10.1 | Transition to OK
PS2 12Vaux Fault | EEh | ok  | 10.2 | Transition to OK
Power Unit       | EFh | ok  | 19.1 | Fully Redundant
```

The problem is, however, it's telling me everything is working. When I removed a cable from the PSU it still told me both PSUs are working.

Comment: Please tell us more about what you did and what you expect and what you're actually getting.

Comment: @schaiba i added the command i used and eddited the question to make it more clear what i want to ask

Comment: Thank you. Now paste the output of your command after removing the cable.

Comment: @schaiba it seems that i was incorrect with my statement... now the ipmitool give me correct state back... i am sorry for wasting your time :(

Comment: Can someone please vote for close as Off Topic as not reproducible

Comment: We should leave it, someone might benefit from the information here.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
ipmitool sdr elist
```

it will show the accurate result.